# new project keeps uploading the old one

Tags: obj

I am new to blender so I think I might have accidently activated a setting, whenever I open a  new project it keeps opening one of my old one , instead of a default cube it load a few modified cylinders. I would appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: you must have saved your project as startup file (File > Defaults > Save Startup File0. So go into File > Defaults > Load Factory Settings.

Comment: oh yea it worked thank you